# Proprietary bare-bone ASP web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I want to create a proprietary minimal / bare-bone / data-light webservice. I prefer not to use the standard solutions like Restful, WebAPI, SOAP, WCF, etc.

I just want a web server listener that can receive and process 1 UTF8 string (own message format) and respond with 1 UTF8 string as the result.

My question is: can you give me a starting point, by providing a code example of the interface. Of course not the complete implementation.

Data transfer has to be as minimal as possible (no avoidable headers).

NB: Server language has to be .NET. Code example may be in C# or VB.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You're not expecting us to make this for you right?

Comment: Of course not. Just a starting point. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most bare-bone thing to create a web service would be an [HTTP Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The sample I linked returns HTML but you could send back XML as well (or anything else really, just make sure to return an appropriate Content Type).

The call to your method would be a regular HTTP call of the URL of your Handler.

Comment: Yes, this is just what I need.

Comment: Alright but be sure it matches the expectation of your consumer base as this will results in a non-standard Web Service (communication-wise) disallowing consumer to use their favorite wrapper. Now if the service is really simple or you're the only consumer then its ok but otherwise people may find it confusing/annoying.

Comment: This web service is proprietary on both sides, only used by our client and server applications.